# Can/how-do you take a Lebesgue integral of a function that has a bijective inverse?

Tags: calculus

Just for simplicity's sake, let's say I'm dealing with a function defined as the integral of $$y=x^{2}$$, which of course is $$\frac{1}{3}*x^{3}+C$$. What if I wanted to integrate with respect to dy and do that sideways Lebesgue integral? Is it still possible somehow? My understanding is that when you are integrating with respect to $dx$, in order to integrate with respect to $dy$, you must find the inverse of $f(x)$ and integrate that inverse. But the inverse of x^2 obviously has two values, so...I'm not sure what the process is or how I pick boundaries of integration.

Comment: For more on typesetting your formulas, take a look at this post: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0):

For easy functions like yours you can proof that the Riemann integral and Lebesgue integral coincide. So it is in facr simpler to just calculate the Riemann integral.

A thorough treatment of Lebesgue integrals would tell you that Lebesgue integration theory involves a bit more than just integrating the inverse function.

Comment: Right but I don't actually care about calculating the Riemann integral, obviously I can already calculate it. This topic is about the process of calculating the Lebesgue integral. And this isn't necessarily restricted to number theory either, this is just regular calculus but with respect to dy.

Comment: Only for pathological cases you will use Lebesgue integration in practice using its convergence theorems.

Comment: Take for example a look at https://rutherglen.science.mq.edu.au/wchen/lnilifolder/lnili.html

Comment: I added a link in comment if you want to learn more on Lebesgue integration.